# Keyboard Accelerator with QInputDialog via QWinWidget

Tags: c++, qt, mfc, qt4, qt5

I am trying to integrate QT5.3 with a legacy SDI MFC (Visual Studio 2013) app using QTWinMigrate. From an option in the main menu bar, I would like to open a QInputDialog to ask the user for a string. This works fine in principle, but keyboard accelerators (Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V etc) do not work in the QInputDialog:

```
QWinWidget wid((CWnd *) AfxGetMainWnd());
wid.showCentered();
QString s = QInputDialog::getText(&wid, ...);
```

Is this a bug in QWinWidget/QInputDialog? Can I somehow get around it? If I create other types of QT windows with QWinWidget as parent, the keyboard accelerators work fine...

Comment: *qtwinmigrate* was meant to migrate MFC applications to Qt. It never served as an integration framework. And it was abandoned roughly a decade ago. Today, it's unmaintained and unsupported. Mixing MFC and Qt has more severe issues, like breaking MFC's leak detection. A VS 2013 MFC project is also anything but *legacy*. Sad as it may be: MFC is still the only officially supported framework for Windows API programming. Use it, and your users will have a higher quality UI than Qt will ever allow for.

Comment: thanks for your perspective! It's really a legacy project, but of course kept in sync with the latest VC++ releases. Btw, QTWinmigrate was not abandoned, as you can see from the commits: https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions/qt-solutions/commits/67a72e3bc2e49ffc9e99b9845b1c314bf86f6941

Comment: A commit comment like *"Update copyright year in Digia's license headers"* does not sound much like maintenance to me. The commits you see are basically to make it compile. This is different from making it work. And there is no official support from Digia (I tried). I can only recommend that you keep going with MFC exclusively, or switch to Qt completely. The latter is not at all recommended if you value your customers (bloated deployment packages, deployment maintenance hell, poor UI performance, crappy keyboard support, virtually no touch input support).